# Is it possible to apply Scipy interpolation functions on MongoDB aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, scipy, aggregation-framework

Can I use on a aggregation stage `$group` a Scipy function `RectBivariateSpline` using GeoJson coordinates and a quantity like:

```
{
    "_id": {"$date": 1452988800000}, 
    "matrix": [
        {"lat": 41.90415308, "lon": -7.49897868, "rain": 0.0}, 
        {"lat": 41.90415308, "lon": -7.5215012, "rain": 0.0}, 
        {"lat": 41.90415308, "lon": -7.47645616, "rain": 0.0}, 
        {"lat": 41.88163056, "lon": -7.49897868, "rain": 0.0}, 
        {"lat": 41.88163056, "lon": -7.5215012, "rain": 0.0}, 
        {"lat": 41.88163056, "lon": -7.47645616, "rain": 0.0}
    ]
}
```

My goal is to interpolate the rain for multiple coordinates and for a given timestamp given by `$date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use clientside functions. Aggregation happens on the serverside. You can use basic javascript for map-reduce, and [aggregation operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) in aggregation framework.